# Can I use VLOOKUP to return a table name that is then used in an INDEX formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

I have an INDEX formula like this:

```
=INDEX(Data3,MATCH(G4,Sheet2!$A$14:$A$17,0),VLOOKUP(F4,Threshold,2,TRUE))
```

However, I want to apply this to data where the table I want the INDEX formula to return data from could be one of three tables 'Data1, Data2, or Data3 depending on a third factor.

I thought I could solve this as follows:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(D4,ChargeYear,2,TRUE),MATCH(G4,Sheet2!$A$14:$A$17,0),VLOOKUP(F4,Threshold,2,TRUE))
```

The 1st VLOOKUP does return either Data1, Data2 or Data3 from the ChargeYear table but it puts the return value in double quotes because it is a text value (I assume) and so the INDEX formula doesn't recognize this as a table name.
Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Using indirect would be an option -

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(1,Table4,2,0)&"[#ALL]"),MATCH("c",INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(1,Table4,2,0)&"[[#All],[Column1]]")),2)
```

*My pictures aren't displaying correctly, so here are links to [the formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olc58.png) and [the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FF4V.png).*

Table4 starts in `A1`; Table5 in `A6`; and Table6 in `D6`.

You can see `=VLOOKUP(1,Table4,2,0)` gives you a reference to one of the tables listed within the table.

So, we expand that to `=MATCH("c",INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(1,Table4,2,0)&"[[#All],[Column1]]"))` to use that table to match "c". It works with `indirect`.

Now, expand it to an index/match like this - `=INDEX(INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(1,Table4,2,0)&"[#ALL]"),MATCH("c",INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(1,Table4,2,0)&"[[#All],[Column1]]")),2)`

Comment: My Excel is a bit limited. Am I correct in thinking then that INDIRECT converts text to a reference such as a cell or table? I just like to understand what I have done rather than just copy it! Thank you for your help

Comment: yes exactly @ZoeH

Comment: Did this work out for you, @ZoeH?